# How to fix Python 400 'Bad Request' error with post requests?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am unable to get the response of my post request. It gives me 400 error. while in postman, it works fine.

The code is below

```
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

url = ""

payload = """[{{\n  \"dateOfBirth\": \"{}\",\n  \"nationalIdentityNo\": \"{}\"\n}}]"""

headers = {
    'x-req-id': "89567890987610",
    'x-channel-id': "MB",
    'x-sub-channel-id': "MB",
    'x-country-code': "PK",
    'x-customer-type': "C",
    'Authorization': "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJrZXkiOiJhZGlsIn0.mRSZXF0glqRPyo2h15jHd51JwCeEnSUIBmYuTaAzmrQ",
    'accept': "application/json",
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "566b2e63-9320-4a59-9524-f480f33fd62f,f7ba71fd-503a-451c-8817-2198f09c1d0c",
    'Host': "*********",
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'Content-Length': "75",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
}

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload.format(new_date, IDNO), headers=headers, verify=False)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

This is result I am getting.

400

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Bad Request</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your JSON payload is not valid. You need to use double quotes instead of single quotes. Better yet, use the json module to build your payload instead of using str.format.

Comment: Remove single quotes of curly braces in your payload.

Comment: I changed my payload to this by extracting the code from postman.
"""[{{\n  \"dateOfBirth\": \"{}\",\n  \"nationalIdentityNo\": \"{}\"\n}}]"""

But it is not taking variable and giving me error of missing nationalIdentityNo with 400 status

Comment: @Justin Ezequiel I tried your advice but i am getting key error. 

payload = "{\n  \"dateOfBirth\": \"{}\",\n  \"nationalIdentityNo\": \"{}\"\n}"

payload = json.dumps(payload)

Error:
KeyError: '\\n  \\"dateOfBirth\\"'

Comment: You do realise your `url` variable is just an empty string?

Comment: @daudnadeem Sorry i deliberately typed an empty here, off course i do have a valid url

Comment: @AliKhan ah, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp

```
url = "string"
payload = [{'key':'value'},]  # a JSON object
headers = {'key':'value'}  # a dictionary
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Did you try this, instead of using a stringified JSON object as payload?

Comment: how do i pass a variable in value of payload?

Comment: The way you are passing to the string using `format`. Create a `dict` instead of formatting a `string`. As it appears you are constructing the JSON string manually.

Answer (score 1):

Your `headers` JSON is incorrect. The key has single quotes. Correct JSON requires `"key":"value"` in double quotes, unless a value is an integer! Try changing all quotes to double quotes in your header.

Also your payload is quite confusing

`payload = """[{{\n  \"dateOfBirth\": \"{}\",\n  \"nationalIdentityNo\": \"{}\"\n}}]"""`

Just make this in your response directly
`data='{{"dateOfbirth": {},"nationalIdentityNo": {}}}'.format(new_date, IDNO)`

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. Please note that the issue is in payload. If i don't pass any variable in it and pass a value, it works fine. But if i pass a variable it gives me key error

Comment: you are formatting in the {} right? like: `payload = """[{{\n  \"dateOfBirth\": \"{}\",\n  \"nationalIdentityNo\": \"{}\"\n}}]""".format("first", "second")`

Comment: I have a strong feeling you aren't passing in the variables into your payload. You need to do `.format(date_of_birth, nationail_id_no)`

Comment: I tried to replace my payload with your suggestion. It gives me 400 Bad Request error

Comment: Before your request can you do: `print("POST", url, data=payload.format(new_date, IDNO), headers=headers, verify=False)` and paste output?

Comment: print("POST", json_url, data=payload.format(new_date, IDNO), headers=headers, verify=False)
---
TypeError: 'data' is an invalid keyword argument for print()

Comment: Do: `print("POST", url, payload.format(new_date, IDNO), headers=headers, verify=False)` This should show you what everything looks like, and make it easier to debug. Paste output here and I'll have a look! Put this line right before `response = requests...`